# Write errors to file

Tags: r

Is there a way to write my R errors to a file? I run R on bash via:

```
R --vanilla < myprogram > myprogram.out &
```

When my program encounters an error (not a syntax error...like an illegal replacement or something) it stops but the error line isn't written to the output file and I don't know what the program was and a lot of the time I log out from the server while it runs.

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `R CMD BATCH <infile> <outfile>` syntax instead.